# Taylor expansion of a function in $R^n$

Tags: real-analysis

I have this function f:$\mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R,n>2$ defined so
$$
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\ \| x \|^2 e^\frac{-1}{\|x\|^2}&\|x\|\ne0\\
0&\|x\|=0.
\end{cases}
$$
$x=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$ and $x_0=(0,0,0,....,0,1)$

How can I found Taylor expansion  of second order in $x_0$ and tangent plane?

Comment: So you'd rather write f than $f$, and you'd prefer $R^n$ to $\mathbb R^n$ and $||x||$ to $\|x\|.$ Why?

Comment: Observe that $e^{-1/\|x\|^2} \le 1,$ so $\|x\|^2 e^{-1/\|x\|^2}\le x^2,$ and thus $f(x)\to0$ as $\|x\|\to0.$ That shows the function is continuous at $x=0.$ Then $$ \left. \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x_1} \right|_{x=0} = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(0+h,0,\ldots,0) - f(0,0,\ldots,0) } h = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{h^2 e^{-1/h^2}} h = 0 $$ That gets you all of the first partial derivatives at $0.$ Then there's more work to do to get $\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i\,\partial x_j}$ at $0.$ That's what you need. $\qquad$

Comment: May help: [Taylors Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem?wprov=sfla1)

Comment: the point is (0,0,....,1)